# if $x^TAx = 0$, can we conclude that $x \in N(A)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I encountered a this problem in controllability prove in my textbook. The author went naturally from $x^TAx = 0$ to $x \in N(A)$ I'm struggling to find a proof. Can someone provide some insight? Thanks

Comment: If $A$ is positive definite then $x^TAx=0$ implies $x=0$.

Comment: In the plane, if $A$ is a $90^\circ$ rotation then $x^TAx=0$ for **any** $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $N(A)$ is the null space of $A$, it is not true in general. For example, let $A = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, $x = (0,1)$.